# R: xts complex queries

Tags: r, xts

Why can't I use the `&` operator in xts objects when querying dates?
For example, these will work:

```
myts[myts$Symbol == "AAPL" & myts$Size > 100, c("Symbol", "Size")]
myts['2011-09-21', c("Symbol", "Size")]
```

But this AND condition on a date/time query will not work:

```
myts[myts$Symbol == "AAPL" & '2011-09-21', c("Symbol", "Size")]
Error in `&.default`("2011-09-21", myts$Symbol == "AAPL") : 
   operations are possible only for numeric, logical or complex types
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`"2011-09-21"` is not a logical vector and cannot be coerced to a logical vector.  See `?"&"` for details.

xts' ISO-8601 style subsetting is nice, but there's nothing we can do to change the behavior of `.Primitive("&")`.  You can do something like this though:

```
myts[myts$Symbol == "AAPL" & index(myts) == as.POSIXct("2011-09-21"),]
```

Comment: Is there another way to query an xts object for both time indexes and some column content?

Comment: Almost there. It's not exactly a perfect match on the date that I need, but rather "grep" all rows for "2011-09-21". I have multiple rows with the same date but different time.

Comment: @RobertKubrick: then you can do something like `as.Date(index(x),tz="America/Chicago")=="2011-09-21"`, but be sure to account for the timezone.

Answer (score 3):

Another way to solve this using a double indexing:

```
myts[myts$Symbol == "AAPL"]['2011-09-21']
```